# How to update the background-image size dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to programming and currently experimenting on my first mini-project - a word definition game.

I have an event listener on an input field, which changes the background image each time a certain score is reached. My issue is that each time the background image is changed, it loses it's CSS style properties, namely, `backgroundSize = cover;`.

I made a function to change the `backgroundSize` value to `cover`, and this only works if I call it in the console. I have also tried inline styles, to no effect.

I just can't get it to work through the javascript file (neither `eventListener` nor an if statement).

The loaded image is always set to `auto`, I need this to be "cover".

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

```
body {
    background: url("/IMG/moebius.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


let changeBackground = () => {
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    return document.body.style.backgroundSize;
}


defInputField.addEventListener("keyup", () => {

    // document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";


    setTimeout(userScore, scoreInterval);
    if (splitInputWords.length < 2) {
        correct.style.display = "none";
        incorrect.style.display = "none";
        displayScore.style.display = "none";
    };

    if (totalScore > 5) {
        document.body.style.background = "url('/IMG/moebius3.jpg')";

    };

    if (totalScore > 10) {
        document.body.style.background = "url('/IMG/moebius.jpg')";

    };

    if (userScore() >= 3 || userScore() >= splitDisplayedDef().length) {
        correct.style.display = "block";
        incorrect.style.display = "none"
        displayScore.textContent = userScore();
        displayScore.style.display = "block";


    } else {
        incorrect.style.display = "none";
        correct.style.display = "none";
        displayScore.display ="none";
    }; 

});

defInputField.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {



    if (e.keyCode === 13 && userScore() >= 1) {
            totalScore += userScore();
            totalScore--;
            currentLevel++;
            newDefButton.textContent = "Definition"
            let newWordObject = newWordObjectGenerator();
            displayNewDef.style.display = "none";
            correct.style.display = "none";
            incorrect.style.display = "none";
            displayScore.style.display = "none";    
            defInputField.value = "";
            displayNewWord.textContent = newWordObject.word;
            displayNewDef.textContent = newWordObject.definition;
            scoreTracker.textContent = "Total Score = " + " " + totalScore;
            levelTracker.textContent = "Level = " + " " + currentLevel;
            console.log(currentLevel);
            console.log(totalScore);

}});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code as a [MRE] _within your question_.

Comment: Could you reduce your code to a minimal example of how you've implemented this?

Comment: try in css set background-size: cover !important;

Comment: I've included the main bits of code but it's a mess in there and I don't have a firm enough grasp of all this stuff yet to minimise effectively. I plan to 'reformat', I just want to get this issue out the way first.

Comment: `style.background` is a [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) for a number of different `background-*` properties. This means that when you use `style.background` you override all of those other properties, including `backgroundSize`. Use `style.backgroundImage` instead.

Comment: Thanks all! Especially @EveryScreamer (it took me a while to realise the "!important", i thought it was just bad english :P) and Turnip, spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `backgroundImage` instead of `background` when u call an image path.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, you've probably saved me 20+ hours of clueless debugging.

Comment: Didn't notice the sneaky grey tick there, accepted. No vote as this is my first post.